# div class with some weird jquery attached in IE

Tags: jquery, html

The code is  `<div class="clickplus"></div>` which works fine in chrome/FF

But in IE 8 I get it as `<div class="clickplus" jQuery164045256094993473433="37">` what does it mean actually?

I have never seen such kind of behaviour in IE before.Is it a new addition? One thing that is the class clickplus has got a onclick function in jQuery.

Comment: please add the jQuery code as well.

Comment: looks like you missed some syntax there.... check that input...this should not happen..unless you are using other plugins

Comment: where is your jQuery code? what other jquery api are you referencing?

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760714/jquery-attribute-auto-added-to-elements

Comment: It's fixed now.Actually the class plus was not working properly in the IE due to position absolute.Once it starts showing the clickplus button everything is fine.Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

Declare the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Hey Chris...I am using html5.It was really a weird problem but not it's fixed.Somehow the IE was not getting the div element.Thanks.