# JQuery on IE8 puts me sizzle attributes and affects on my CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, internet-explorer-8

I have a very strange problem with JQuery in a JSP. My code before compile is:

```
<table id="tablaRadioButtons" class="estiloTabla">
    <tr>
        <td class="W50">                
            <input type="radio" name="opcionCS" value="cambio" checked 
                <c:if test="${!habilitarCampos}">disabled</c:if>                
            ><bean:message key="servicios.ui.cambio.servicio"/>
        </td>
        <td class="W50">
            <input type="radio" name="opcionCS" value="cierre" 
                <c:if test="${!habilitarCampos}">disabled</c:if>
            ><bean:message key="servicios.ui.cambio.servicio.cierre.hc"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="tablaCambioServicio" class="estiloTabla">
    <!-- Some code -->
</table>
<table id="tablaCierreHC" class="estiloTabla" style="display:none">
    <!-- More code -->  
</table>
```

And my JS:

```
$("[name='opcionCS']").click(function(){
     if ($(this).val() == "cambio"){
        document.getElementById('tablaCambioServicio').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('tablaCierreHC').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('guardarBotonCierre').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('cierreBoton').style.display = 'none';
     }
     else{
        document.getElementById('tablaCambioServicio').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tablaCierreHC').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('guardarBotonCierre').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('cierreBoton').style.display = '';
     }
});
```

As you can see, when you click one of the radio buttons, one of the tables will show up and the other will be hidden.

Well, the problem is in IE8 when I show the JSP. When I inspect code I have:

```
<table class="estiloTabla" id="tablaRadioButtons" sizzle-1409812390796="[object Object]">
  <tbody sizzle-1409812390796="[object Object]">
    <tr sizzle-1409812390796="[object Object]">
        <td class="W50" sizzle-1409812390796="[object Object]">                 
            <input name="opcionCS" type="radio" CHECKED="checked" jQuery11020918187712285087="126" value="cambio"/><bean:message key="servicios.ui.cambio.servicio"/>
        </td>
        <td class="W50" sizzle-1409812390796="[object Object]">
            <input name="opcionCS" type="radio" jQuery11020918187712285087="128" value="cierre"/><bean:message key="servicios.ui.cambio.servicio.cierre.hc"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="estiloTabla" id="tablaCambioServicio" sizzle-1409812390796="[object Object]">
    <!-- Some code with sizzle attribute -->
</table>
<table class="estiloTabla" id="tablaCierreHC" style="display: none;" sizzle-1409812390796="[object Object]">
    <!-- More code with sizzle attribute -->
</table>
```

And JS code doesn't change at least.

Now, when you click on radio items, the event works well, but style attributes doesn't change and tables doesn't a space between them (see images):

[image: First table]
[image: Second table]

What's happen?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337859/weird-issue-in-ie7-only-not-in-any-other-browser). What is the browser mode you were using(IE8 compatibility)?

Comment: I have big difficulties understanding what exactly your question/problem is.